# How can I scrape links from a the job classifieds website monster.com?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

## I would like to scrape URLS for specific job classifies from a [monster.com](https://www.monster.com/jobs/search/?q=python&where=aurora__2C-co&stpage=1&page=2) page which displays search results:

[image]

## If you go look at the html, you will see that the URLS are in a block like this:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
            {"@context":"https://schema.org","@type":"ItemList","mainEntityOfPage":{
            "@type":"CollectionPage","@id":"https://www.monster.com/jobs/search/?q=python&amp;where=aurora__2C-co&amp;stpage=1&amp;page=10"
            }
            ,"itemListElement":[

                 {"@type":"ListItem","position":2251,"url":"https://job-openings.monster.com/19-16001-senior-python-developer-boulder-co-us-sunrise-systems-inc/e09cfe38-2a32-465d-bd66-8846b9549c6a"}
```

## The desired output for our web scraping program is a list of strings:

```
L = [
    "https://job-openings.monster.com/senior-python-architect-boulder-co-us-experis/26b7c4e8-ec4f-4d93-84e4-959fd28e150a",
    "https://job-openings.monster.com/predictive-analytics-developer-python-100-remote-denver-co-us-edp-recruiting-services/e5041b2e-28fd-4036-9f17-0a3510a457dc",
    "https://job-openings.monster.com/python-automation-engineer-denver-co-us-apidel-technologies/77e8f683-2e91-403f-b663-def61b62226e",
    "https://job-openings.monster.com/immediate-need-for-python-developer-6-month-contract-onsite-in-boulder-co-boulder-co-us-addon-technologies-inc/e2826a70-490b-4e16-a4bb-05e767c8fb1f",
    "https://job-openings.monster.com/software-test-technician-englewood-co-us-kratos-defense-security-solutions/fa39cdfe-0fe8-4e02-b325-28f21561ac33" 
]
```

### The webpage which displays search results ends in a `page=1` parameter. We want to increment this until the "Load more jobs" button becomes a "No More Results" message.

[image: picture]

### My code is supplied below. It does not work very well:

```
import itertools as itts
import string
import urllib.request

# BEFORE CLICK `LOAD MORE JOBS` BUTTON
#    https://www.monster.com/jobs/search/?q=python&where=aurora__2C-co&stpage=1&page=2
# AFTER CLICK LOAD MORE JOBS
#    https://www.monster.com/jobs/search/?q=python&where=aurora__2C-co&stpage=1&page=3
# AT END OF URL, `page=2` changes to `page=3`

prefix = "https://www.monster.com/jobs/search/?q=python&where=aurora__2C-co&stpage=1&page=1"

sentinel = """
<a class="mux-btn btn-secondary no-more-jobs-btn disabled "
style="display:none" id="noMoreResults" role="button">No More Results</a>
"""
predicate = lambda ch, string=string:\
    ch not in "\n\r"
sentinel = str(filter(predicate, sentinel))

for page_num in range(1, 90):
    print("page_num ==", page_num)
    fp = urllib.request.urlopen(prefix + str(page_num))
    mybytes = fp.read()
    page_html = mybytes.decode("utf8")
    fp.close()
    if sentinel in page_html:
        break
# `page_html` is the output of the script above

print("len(page_html) == len(page_html)")

class LineIter:
    def __init__(self, stryng):
        self.it = it(str(stryng))
        self.delims = "\n\r"
        self.depleted = False
    def __next__(self):
        if self.depleted:
            raise StopIteration()
        try:
            while True:
                ch = next(self.it)
                if ch not in self.delims:
                    break
            line = list()
            while ch not in self.delims:
                line.append(ch)
                ch = next(self.it)
            r = "".join(line)
        except StopIteration:
            self.depleted = True
            try:
                r = "".join(line)
            except BaseException:
                r = ""
        return r

urls = list()
for line in LineIter(page_html):
    print(line)
    start = line.find("https://job-openings.monster.com/")
    if start >= 0:
        stop = line.find('"', start)
        urls.append(line[start:stop])
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using their [API](https://partner.monster.com/job-search-v2)?

Comment: share the output you get

Answer (score 0):

As I already mentioned in a comment, generally you can avoid stuff like this by just using the [provided API](https://partner.monster.com/job-search-v2).

As for the question you asked, however: manually searching the HTML string is going to be very painful and error-prone. Here's how it can be done better.

First, use [BeautifulSoup](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/) to parse the HTML for you:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.monster.com/jobs/search/?q=python&where=aurora__2C-co&stpage=1&page=2'
html = requests.get(url).text

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
```

Now you can search for and extract the `<script>` tag that has the data you're looking for:

```py
tags = soup('script', {'type': 'application/ld+json'})

# On this page, the data is in the second of two tags. You'll want to verify this for other pages.
tag = tags[-1]
```

Then you can parse the content of the tag as JSON:

```py
import json

data = json.loads(tag.text)
```

And access the data within as a dictionary:

```py
>>> data['itemListElement']
[{'@type': 'ListItem',
  'position': 51,
  'url': 'https://job-openings.monster.com/predictive-analytics-developer-python-100-remote-denver-co-us-edp-recruiting-services/e5041b2e-28fd-4036-9f17-0a3510a457dc'},
#
# [...]
#
 {'@type': 'ListItem',
  'position': 108,
  'url': 'https://job-openings.monster.com/uipath-rpa-architect-denver-co-us-enquero/f14cc922-dd4d-4636-a3d4-dc3b18eec843'}]
```

To get your desired output, just extract all the urls as a list, filtering any empty strings:

```py
>>> [el['url'] for el in data['itemListElement'] if el['url']]
['https://job-openings.monster.com/predictive-analytics-developer-python-100-remote-denver-co-us-edp-recruiting-services/e5041b2e-28fd-4036-9f17-0a3510a457dc',
 'https://job-openings.monster.com/python-automation-engineer-denver-co-us-apidel-technologies/77e8f683-2e91-403f-b663-def61b62226e',
# [...]
 'https://job-openings.monster.com/full-stack-java-engineer-denver-co-us-srinav-inc/fda6f2fd-be2f-4199-90eb-585ff8f96874',
 'https://job-openings.monster.com/uipath-rpa-architect-denver-co-us-enquero/f14cc922-dd4d-4636-a3d4-dc3b18eec843']
```